# Number Manipulation from Strings 

Tags: java, string, numbers

I am trying to figure out how to do two things :

1. Change a number from a `String` to a `double` and back to a `String`.
2. How to manipulate different parts of a `double`.

To explain :

In the first case, I would like the user to be able to input a number into the a `JTextArea` so I can store the input in a variable (simple). Then, I would like to perform operations on the number that is inputted, but this cannot be done with a string. Is there any way to convert input into a `double`?

Then, I would like to take this string, after it has been converted into a double, and analyze the specific digits, and the digits of its decimal places (tenths, hundredths, etc.) as well using if-else and for statements (I can do this part). My understanding of strings is that, if I say `NameofString[0]`, I will get the first letter of the string, but can this be done with a `Number`?

Lastly, I would like to convert this `double` back into a `String`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can parse a string using (assuming `x` is a double variable and `s` a string)

```
x = Double.parseDouble(s);
```

and convert the number back to a string via

```
s = Double.toString(x);
```

If you want to format the value according to a specific format you may want to use [`String.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) instead.

Comment: That looks like it will do it!

Answer (score 1):

Also, `NameofString[0]` will not work in Java. but you can call `myString.charAt(0)` though. To your question about extracting digits from a double would either require conversion to a string or doing some math on the number to pull digits out.

Answer (score 1):

The translation part is discussed in the answer by @Howard, Now for analyzing specific digits, I suppose you need to use the `/` and `%` judiciously.

say for example,

```
while(x!>0)
{
  x%10    // will return the digit at the tenths position.

   Now,

  x=x/10  //will give you the remaining part.

}
```

Comment: That is very helpful, without a doubt! I would like to give two answer checks; this one deserves it, too.